# Windows 8 Metro Style App: multi-app package

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I want to raise a Toast Notification from one app via another, by using the `ToastNotificationManager::CreateToastNotifier(String appID)`.

I've understood that it can be only when the two apps are belong to the same multi-app package.

And to the questions:

1. What is "multi-app package" and how to create it?
2. Is the "multi-app package" can hold also Desktop Application, or only Metro Style Apps?
3. What is PRAID (Package Relative Applicatin ID), and from where I can get it?

Answer (score 1):

1) A multi-app package is a package containing multiple applications (i.e. 1 appx, more than one tile/application)
2) No, it can only hold Metro style apps
3) PRAID is the application ID in the manifest. Each Application in the Applications tag can has an ID which is it's PRAID.

Note that VS isn't tooled to create multi-app packages. You'll have to do it manually by adding the extra applications and elements to the app manifest